# Yocto : Custom colored output in recipes?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, recipe

#### Context

When I'm using bitbake to process recipes with Yocto, I'd like to be able to print useful output on the screen. There exist a few ways to do this so far, but they're not very practical. Let me enumerate the default options:

1. Using: `bbinfo "my message"` with `bitbake --verbose`
2. Using: `bbdebug 1 "my message"` with `bitbake -D` (scaling is possible for more debug levels)
3. Using: `bbwarn "my message"` with no extra flags

---

#### Problem

Using option (1) outputs a lot of unnecessary clutter on the terminal, and also suffers from having no colored output. Option (2) is colored, but unfortunately also captures a lot of debugging messages from the other build components, which floods the output. I've been using option (3) for now, as it makes my messages stand out without also enabling other irrelevant information from appearing.

So my question is, how can I enable custom logging (i.e. in green, or blue) for my own messages? It would make it easier for me to distinguish important output I want without accidentally enabling unnecessary information from appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbake is the one taking care of printing log messages in their appropriate colors. You could add new kinds of log messages if you want with different colors by modifying: https://gitlab.com/yoctoproject/poky/-/blob/master/bitbake/lib/bb/build.py#L475 seems to be where the bbwarn/bbdebug/bbplain/etc... shell commands are translated to Python's bb.warn, bb.debug, bb.plain, etc.. defined here: https://gitlab.com/yoctoproject/poky/-/blob/master/bitbake/lib/bb/__init__.py#L132-165 and whose colors and loglevels are defined in BBLogFormatter class defined here: https://gitlab.com/yoctoproject/poky/-/blob/master/bitbake/lib/bb/msg.py#L22

I'd personally try to add warning levels the same way as different debug levels are handled and then you can associate a warning level to a particular color.

This however modifies bitbake itself, which is not possible via bbappends or other btibake mechanisms as they are Python scripts.

Otherwise, I'm wondering if it would not be possible to just have your own logger defined in/for the recipes/tasks/functions you want to use it, e.g. have a bbclass which sets up everything you need with the Python `logging` module and just use this instead of bbwarn or bb.warn.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually tried adding my own python functions, using `printf` and then even bash functions with `echo` to try to print messages to screen. However, it seems Yocto is directing that somewhere other than STDOUT, because it isn't appearing onscreen. Only messages using the logging functionality appeared.

Comment: If we can confirm that there isn't any other way to get messages to appear beyond modifying bitbake itself then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I am not too surprised, it's probably stored in `${WORKDIR}/temp/log.do_<task>` instead of printed on the console.

Comment: I don't forsee a better workaround besides modifying Yocto ATM, so I will accept your answer.